# I want to stop auto scrolling when I search the record?

Tags: javascript, ajax, html

I have auto scroll-er on my index page and also I have a search functionality on that page when I search for the record they give the result. When I scroll down the page a new record is added automatically.  I want to disable the auto loader when I search the record that's it. Does anybody have an idea?

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
$().ready(function () {
    $("#hdnStudentCount").val(5);
});

function AddStudentRecord() {
           $.ajax({
        type: 'Get',
        url: '/Home/getdeal',
        data: {
            lastdeal: parseInt($("#hdnStudentCount").val()) + 1,
        },

        async: false,
        dataType: "html",
        success: function (data) {
              data = JSON.parse(data);
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

                if (data[i] != '') {
                    $("#studentTemplate").tmpl(data[i]).appendTo("#divMain");
                    var DealID = (data[i]["DealID"]);
                    $("#hdnStudentCount").val(parseInt(DealID));
                    $('div#last_msg_loader').html('<img src="/Images/ajax-loade.gif">');
                }

            }

        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            alert(xhr.status);
            alert(thrownError);
        }
    });
}

$(window).scroll(function () {

    if ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()) {
        AddStudentRecord();
    }
});
$('#developer').click(function (e) {
    // do something fancy
    return false; // prevent default click action from happening!
    e.preventDefault(); // same thing as above
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are having a form for search so there might be some changes in url of page ie it might be changing url of page to something like

> ...../search?attr_name=value&.....

You can check if there is 'search' in 'window.location.href' like

```
$(window).scroll(function () {

  if ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height() && (window.location.href.indexOf('/search') === -1)) {
      AddStudentRecord();
  }
});
```

**Else** 
When your search request is sent then you can set some variable on window object like

> window.isSearching = true

And you can check that variable in if condition like

```
$(window).scroll(function () {

  if ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height() && (typeof(window.isSearching) === 'undefined')) {
      AddStudentRecord();
  }
});
```